# Implementing a Simple Vector Example With Templates Causing Undefined Symbol Error

Tags: c++

Can anyone tell me why I am getting the error Undefined Symbol: Vector::Vector(int)?

I am trying to learn the language by making a simple vector class.

The first iteration used doubles as elements. Now I am trying to get it to work with templates so it will work with any type. It was working fine until I did that. I must have implemented it wrong.

Here is the code:

```
//main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "Vector.h"
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    // insert code here...
    std::cout << "Hello, World!\n";

    Vector<int> a(5);
    Vector<int> b(5);

    return 0;
}

//vector.h
#ifndef Vector_h
#define Vector_h

template<typename T>
class Vector {
public:
    explicit Vector(int s); // constr uctor: establish invariant, acquire resources
    ~Vector() { delete[] elem; } // destructor: release resources
    // ... copy and move operations ...
    T& operator[](int i); // for non-const Vectors
    const T& operator[](int i) const; // for const Vectors (§4.2.1)
    int size() const { return sz; }


    friend Vector operator+(const Vector& a, const Vector& b);

    Vector(const Vector& a); // copy constructor
    Vector& operator=(const Vector& a); // copy assignment

    Vector(Vector&& a); // move constructor
    Vector& operator=(Vector&& a); // move assignment move assignment operator

    T* begin(Vector<T>& x);
    T* end(Vector<T>& x);

private:
    T* elem; // elem points to an array of sz elements of type T
    int sz;
};

//vector.cpp:
#include <stdio.h>
#include "Vector.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>

template<typename T>
Vector<T>::Vector(int s) // definition of the constructor
//:elem{new double[s]}, sz{s} // initialize members or do whats in bottom here.
{
    elem = new T[s];
    sz = s;
    std::cout << "Main Constructor" << std::endl;
}

    template<typename T>
    T& Vector<T>::operator[](int i) // definition of subscripting
    {
    return elem[i];
    }

    template<typename T>
    const T& Vector<T>::operator[](int i) const // definition of subscripting
    {
    return elem[i];
    }

    template<typename T>
    Vector<T> operator+(const Vector<T>& a, const Vector<T>& b)
    {
    //if (a.size()!=b.size())
    //  throw Vector_size_mismatch{};
    std::cout << "Move Constructor" << std::endl;
    Vector<T> res(a.size());
    for (int i=0; i!=a.size(); ++i)
    res[i]=a[i]+b[i];
    return res;
    }

    template<typename T>
    Vector<T>::Vector(const Vector<T>& a) // copy constructor
    :elem{new double[a.sz]}, // allocate space for elements
    sz{a.sz}
    {
    for (int i=0; i!=sz; ++i) // copy elements
    elem[i] = a.elem[i];
    std::cout << "Copy Constructor" << std::endl;
    }

    template<typename T>
    Vector<T>& Vector<T>::operator=(const Vector<T>& a) // copy assignment
    {
    std::cout << "Copy Assignment Constructor" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Element is " << a[0] << std::endl;
    double* p = new double[a.sz];
    for (int i=0; i!=a.sz; ++i)
    p[i] = a.elem[i];
    delete[] elem; // delete old elements
    elem = p;
    sz = a.sz;
    return *this;
    }

    template<typename T>
    Vector<T>::Vector(Vector<T>&& a) // Move construtor
    :elem{a.elem}, // "grab the elements" from a
    sz{a.sz}
    {
        a.elem = nullptr; // now a has no elements
        a.sz = 0;
    }

    template<typename T>
    Vector<T>& Vector<T>::operator=(Vector<T>&&) { return *this;  } // Move assignment


    template<typename T>
    T* begin(Vector<T>& x)
    {
        return x.size() ? &x[0] : nullptr; // pointer to first element or nullptr
    }
        template<typename T>
    T* end(Vector<T>& x)
    {
        return x.size() ? &x[0]+x.size() : nullptr; // pointer to one-past-last element
    }
```

Comment: What's wrong with `std::vector`?

Comment: Oh nothing. I just need to know how to implement templates correctly :)

Comment: `//vector.cpp
#ifndef Vector_h
#define Vector_h` - why would you have header guards in your *implementation* file?

Comment: Thanks everyone.